# Problems about comment section with Stack Overflow on mobile

Tags: feature-request, comments

While using Stack Overflow in a mobile browser, the suggestions (username) don't pop up in the comments section after typing `@`. Is it intentional? If I type `@username` (through mobile, when there are no name suggestions) will the respective user be notified?

*Note:* Switching to desktop sites works, but it's a little bit of headache to switch to desktop site every time in a new tab.

Comment: To be clear, you mean the mobile version of the stackoverflow.com website, correct? Not the mobile app?

Comment: @HereticMonkey Sorry for not being so specific, on any mobile browser

Comment: Are you using the "mobile" version, or the responsive version? (I'm not sure if the "mobile" version still exists, though).

Comment: Scroll all the way down, click “full site” on the bottom right (you don’t need to do this in every new tab). Then you have the responsive mobile site (if not, click “Enable Responsiveness” at the bottom). Now you can flag comments. To switch back to the old mobile site click “Mobile” at the bottom.

Comment: If you switch to desktop site you'll get the responsive version, which is better all around anyway. The browser should remember your choice (at least mine does, I did it at some point and I always get the responsive version).

Comment: @yivi Mobile browsers have a separate built-in “desktop view” option. Maybe the OP’s browser doesn’t persist this option.

Comment: I am using Chrome

Comment: We certainly still have a separate mobile and responsive version, and you can toggle between them in the footer (the _mobile_ button). The mobile version offers substantially less features, but less clutter as well. You don't need to use desktop view to switch.

Comment: Frankly, I switched at some point and forgot about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can see usernames not being auto completed, but do not feel that as a hassle. I've used the mobile website version for months, close to a year maybe, and have never had a problem with that.

The users will indeed be notified even if there's no auto complete box.

Just in case you didn't know, using the first three letters of a user's handle will also ping them, so you don't really need to write the whole handle <del>(not one hundred percent sure about this, it's like that in chat and I have the impression I've also seen this work in comment boxes).</del>

Comment: [Now you can be one-hundred percent sure](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work/43020#43020).